# Read trailing white space in column name with read.table

Tags: r, whitespace, read.table

Using the code below I would expect that the trailing white spaces in the header are not striped, i.e. that the name of the first column is `Column Name 1[whitespace]` and not `Column Name 1`.

```
names(
read.table(text = 
           "Column Name 1 &ColumnName 2 
  1&2
  1&2
  1&2", sep="&", check.names = FALSE,  header = TRUE, strip.white = FALSE)
)
```

Why does the column name not include the trailing white space and is there a way of reading the text or a table such that the column names include trailing white spaces (besides reading in the first line as character)?

Comment: You can quote the column name to read in the whitespace as well.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: or use `data.table::fread`

Comment: If in the example you gave, it would have said `"'Column Name 1'&Column Name...` instead of just `"Column Name 1 &ColumnName...`, it would have read the whitespace as well.

Answer (score 2):

Strip.white=FALSE avoids stripping white spaces in column values not in column names. By default read.table strip all trailing white spaces in column names.

I think the approach to solve your problem is to read column names separately in a vector and use them while reading rest of the data. This can be done in two lines as following (I have stored your data in a variable named text)

`text<-"Column Name 1 &ColumnName 2 
  1&2
  1&2
  1&2"`

`colnames<-as.character(read.table(text=text,sep = "&",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,nrows = 1))`

`data<-read.table(text=text,sep="&",col.names = colnames,strip.white = FALSE,skip=1,check.names = FALSE)`